# Two dimensional array in Python with strings as indexes for 2nd dimension

Tags: python, arrays

New to Python so am trying to work out some basic stuff.

I'm looping two arrays to create a new two dimensional array which I'd like to end up as follows:

```
new_array[0]['item1'] = "Item 1"
new_array[0]['item2'] = "Item 2"
new_array[1]['item1'] = "Item 1"
new_array[1]['item2'] = "Item 2"
```

etc

What I have currently which isn't working is:

```
new_array = []
i = 0;
Loop...
    new_array[i]['item1'] = "Item 1"
    new_array[i]['item2'] = "Item 2"
    i = i + 1
```

etc

What is the best/correct way to manage this?

Comment: You can't index lists with strings. Use a dictionary instead. Better yet - use a tutorial to learn python - look into this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ and after doing chapters 1 to 5 find https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you cannot index a list by a string, you can do somtheing similar to that with a dictionary. Now, while it's not good practice to teach you about a variable type or function of a variable that does not exist, you can achieve something close to what you wanted in this example with a couple of modifications. You can achieve indexing in this sort by making a list of dictionaries, which you can index as shown here. The code to make this being quite similar to yours:

```
new_array = []
for i in range(NUMBER_OF_DICTIONARIES):
    new_array.append({})
    new_array[i]['item1'] = "Item 1"
    new_array[i]['item2'] = "Item 2"
print(new_array)
```

This code will produce the reults I assume you want, granted you replace the `NUMBER_OF_DICTIONARIES` varible with an actual integer. The structure of this variable would look like this:

`[{'item1': 'Item 1', 'item2': 'Item 2'}, {'item1': 'Item 1', 'item2': 'Item 2'}]`

So, while not an actual python variable, it is close to what you wanted if you wanted to implement something with this index-structure in python. =)

(Quick note: This is *not* a two dimensional array in any way, it is just an array containing multiple dictionaries)